# C# Selenium Automation Application to be executed in Azure Web Jobs

Tags: azure, selenium, testing, automation, webhooks

Task:

I have created a Selenium Automation Scripts using the Visual studio and C# language, I have the set of files including Assemblies [DLL and Executable] in the bin folder of the project.

How does it work?

When I click on the executable it automatically triggers the Firefox and launch the website and check for the automation testing scripts as it is coded, which works as expected when deployed to the "Web Server" box which has the firefox installed.

Where I face Issue?

I have to deploy the same application in the azure environment, instead of deploying in the "App Services" I found it's better to deploy the executable to be deployed as "Web Jobs" which can be executed automatically on daily basis.

When I execute Web jobs in the azure environment, where can I execute the browser from an application? How does this work?

Is azure cannot support this kind of automation testing?

Please suggest me or correct me with the proper way of deployment.

What have I tried?
I deployed the application in Web Jobs, web jobs executes and stops with Filed status after some few seconds, hope it cannot initiate a browser.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way of running automation tests that involve UX interactions is to use Test Agents.

You can use Visual Studio Team Services to Run your Selenium Automation tests in its Test Agents.

VSTS will give you the result of the execution and all the details and outputs of the test run. ALSO it is FREE. If you try to use Azure resources you will have to pay for your consumption.

Here is an article on how to run Selenium Tests from VSTS:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/continuous-test-selenium

If you run it yourself in your own machine or anywhere else you need to deal with reporting out of the trx files or the test results